# Compile old code with gcc on Kali 2.0 64bit

Tags: c, linux, gcc, exploit

I want to compile this old exploit to complete my exercise: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/895/.

After gcc repoted that `<asm/page.h>` was missing.
I searched around the net and found out that a number of headers in `asm` have been moved to:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/include/asm-generic/
```

To make sure that the source file had everything it needed to compile, I made a link for each and every file in the above directory to:

```
/usr/include/asm
/usr/include/asm-generic
```

I ran gcc, this time, it didn't report missing `<asm/page.h>` but `<linux/compiler.h>`
After digging around, I found this:

```
<asm/page.h>
|
|---#include <asm-generic/getorder.h>
                            |
                            |--#include <linux/compiler.h> ==> missing
```

A simple `locate linux/compiler.h` showed me that `compiler.h` was in here

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/include/linux/compiler.h
```

Surely, I could make another link from that `<linux/compiler.h>` to `/usr/include/linux`.

But I don't really know how many of them are left and how many more links I have to make.

Is there any way to tell the compiler that it must fetch the header from the new `include` directory?

Or Am I missing something here?
I'm still new to linux, so any help is appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using Kali 2.0 64 bit and have installed/reinstalled build-essential

**UPDATE:**

I tried `-I` option:

```
gcc source.c -m32 -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/include/
```

This time, gcc said that I need something from

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/
```

(=.=)

Comment: Do not make links. Rather tell the compiler where the headers are with the `-I` flag

Comment: something like this? `gcc source.c -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/include/`

Comment: I think gcc wants the directory combined with the option as `-Idirectory`, but otherwise correct

Comment: Maybe cross-compilation is a better way of solving your problem : http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of a "simulated" older linux (with it's headers, etc.)